# Get the class name of a generic type in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a function `readObjectFromFile` with a generic type T. How can I know the type name?

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{typeOf, TypeTag}

def name[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toString

name[Int]
res5: String = Int

import java.io._

def readObjectFromFile[T](file: File): T = {
  val typeName = name[T]
  println(s"read ${typeName} from file $file")
  val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
  val v = ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[T]
  ois.close()
  v
}

cmd19.sc:2: No TypeTag available for T
  val typeName = name[T]
```

ps: I am aware I could use v.getClass.getName, but this would be done **after** reading the object. I want to print this information before reading the object.

Comment: You normally want to wrap `ois.readObject` in `try` and put `close` in `finally` so that you don't leave the file unclosed on failure.

Comment: or even better use resource allocation in scala; this is not production code; it is just a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readObjectFromFile` needs to require an implicit `TypeTag` as well, in order for `name` to be able to resolve it.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{typeOf, TypeTag}
import java.io._

def name[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toString

def readObjectFromFile[T: TypeTag](file: File): T = {
  val typeName = name[T]
  println(s"read ${typeName} from file $file")
  val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
  val v = ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[T]
  ois.close()
  v
}
```